# How to use a Unix sort command to sort by human-readable numeric file size in a column?

Tags: linux, sorting, unix

This question now answered - scroll to the end of this post for the solution.

Apologies if the answer is already here, but all the answers I have found so far suggest either the -h flag or the -n flag, and neither of those are working for me...

I have some output from a curl command that is giving me several columns of data. One of those columns is a human-readable file size ("1.6mb", "4.3gb" etc).

I am using the unix **sort** command to sort by the relevant column, but it appears to be trying to sort alphabetically instead of numercially. I have tried using both the -n and the -h flags, but although they do change the order, in neither case is the order numerically correct.

I am on CentOS Linux box, version 7.2.1511. The version of **sort** I have is "sort (GNU coreutils) 8.22".

I have tried using the -h flag in these different formats:

```
curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices | sort -k9,9h | head -n5
curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices | sort -k9 -h | head -n5
curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices | sort -k 9 -h | head -n5
curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices | sort -k9h | head -n5
```

I always get these results:

```
green open indexA            5 1        0       0   1.5kb    800b
green open indexB            5 1  9823178 2268791 152.9gb  76.4gb
green open indexC            5 1    35998    7106 364.9mb 182.4mb
green open indexD            5 1      108      11 387.1kb 193.5kb
green open indexE            5 1        0       0   1.5kb    800b
```

I have tried using the -n flag in the same formats as above:

```
curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices | sort -k9,9n | head -n5
curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices | sort -k9 -n | head -n5
curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices | sort -k 9 -n | head -n5
curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices | sort -k9n | head -n5
```

I always get these results:

```
green open index1      5 1     1021       0   3.2mb   1.6mb
green open index2      5 1     8833       0   4.1mb     2mb
green open index3      5 1     4500       0     5mb   2.5mb
green open index4      1 0        3       0   3.9kb   3.9kb
green open index5      3 1  2516794       0   8.6gb   4.3gb
```

Edit: It turned out there were two problems:

1) sort expects to see capital single letters - M, K and G instead of mb, kb and gb (for bytes you can just leave blank).

2) sort will include leading spaces unless you explicitly exclude them, which messes with the ordering.

The solution is to replace lower case with upper case and use the -b flag to make sort ignore leading spaces (I've based this answer on @Vinicius' solution below, because it's easier to read if you don't know regex):

```
curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices | tr '[kmg]b' '[KMG] ' | sort -k9hb
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `--write-out size_download` option on `curl`?

Answer (score 4):

Your 'm' and 'g' units should be uppercase. [GNU `sort` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) reads:

> **-h --human-numeric-sort --sort=human-numeric**
>
> Sort numerically, first by numeric sign (negative, zero, or positive); then by SI suffix (either empty, or ‘k’ or ‘K’, or one of ‘MGTPEZY’, in that order; see Block size); and finally by numeric value.

You can change the output of `curl` with GNU `sed` like this:

```
curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices \
| sed 's/[0-9][mgtpezy]/\U&/g'
| sort -k9,9h \
| head -n5
```

Yields:

```
green open index4      1 0        3       0   3.9kb   3.9kb
green open index1      5 1     1021       0   3.2Mb   1.6Mb
green open index2      5 1     8833       0   4.1Mb     2Mb
green open index3      5 1     4500       0     5Mb   2.5Mb
green open index5      3 1  2516794       0   8.6Gb   4.3Gb
```

Other letters like "b" will be treated as "no unit":

```
green open indexA            5 1        0       0   1.5kb    800b
green open indexE            5 1        0       0   1.5kb    800b
green open indexD            5 1      108      11 387.1kb 193.5kb
green open indexC            5 1    35998    7106 364.9Mb 182.4Mb
green open indexB            5 1  9823178 2268791 152.9Gb  76.4Gb
```

If so desired, you can change the units in the sorted output back to lowercase by piping to `sed 's/[0-9][MGTPEZY]/\L&/g'`

Comment: This nearly worked - not quite because all the numeric columns have leading blanks which sort does not ignore by default. But if you add the -b flag, all is good. Like this: 

curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices | sed 's/[0-9][mgtpezy]/\U&/g' | sort -k9hb | head -n5

Thank you!

Comment: Since blanks separate fields, there should not be any leading blank issue and it's not clear for me why you had to resort to the -b option. Maybe it depends on your locale? (I tested it with en_US.UTF-8; if any doubt try `| LC_ALL=C sort ...`). Don't hesitate to accept my answer if you are happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

`sort` does not understand kb, mb and gb. You have to use K, M and G. You can use `tr` to convert the suffixes:

```
curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices | tr 'kmgb' 'KMG ' | sort -b -k 9 -h
```

Comment: This nearly worked - not quite because all the numeric columns have leading blanks which sort does not ignore by default. But if you add the -b flag, all is good. Like this: 

curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices | tr '[kmg]b' '[KMG] ' | sort -k9hb

Thank you!

Comment: In your `tr` command, `'[kmg]b'` is not a regex. It does not mean "(either k or m or g) followed by b". It means substitute all '[' with '[' (useless), all 'k' with 'K', all 'm' with 'M', all 'g' with 'G', all ']' with ']' (useless), and finally all 'b' with ' '. This will therefore affect the whole line, changing "green" to "Green" (and any "blue" to " lue")

Comment: @xhienne You're right, I so used to regex syntax that I used it here without need. I'll update the answer. As for the green turning to Green if it is an issue the solution will be using a regex like in your response. I just tried to provide the simplest possible solution.

Comment: @ClareSudbery I updated the response to include the -b flag.