# Sorting a du command in linux

Tags: bash

I have a simple script, which runs this command:

`du -h / --max-depth=1 2> /dev/null | sort -nr`

This command searches the folders with a `--max-depth=1`

but the sort command, does not diferencte the `MB` and the `GB` and just sorts by number.

```
895M    /var
8G  /snap
```

Obiously `/snap` in this case is just superior, but sort just takes the numbers and does not classify by types.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a Unix sort command to sort by human-readable numeric file size in a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55926142/how-to-use-a-unix-sort-command-to-sort-by-human-readable-numeric-file-size-in-a)

Comment: See: [List all directories sorted by size in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51443182/3776858)

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer:

`du -h / --max-depth=1 2> /dev/null | sort -rh`

Comment: Good job ^^. Mark your answer to your question as accepted.